# How to Use Select() function in a Data Frame by passing the Column name in a variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to select some specific columns within a data frame using select statement by passing the header names into a variable so as to reduce writing the columns names.

The data frame I am working with is:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), `2022-11-01` = c(1, 
2, 3), `2022-12-01` = c(2, 3, 4), `2023-01-01` = c(2, 2, 3), 
    `2023-02-01` = c(3, 3, 4), `2023-03-01` = c(3, 2, 3), `2023-04-01` = c(4, 
    3, 4), `2023-05-01` = c(4, 2, 3), `2023-06-01` = c(5, 3, 
    4), `2023-07-01` = c(5, 2, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

The code which I wrote is:

```
Book1 <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/Book1.xlsx")
View(Book1)

Time <- '2022-08-01'
Time_Period <- add_months(max(ymd(Time)),1:3)
Time_Period
Book1 %>%
  select(`Row Labels`,any_of(Time_Period))
```

I run into an error in this select statement and not been able to figure out why. Can anyone help me out here. The duplicate which was suggested doesn't work in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: Not sure where `add_months` comes from, but you want to make sure you coerce the date to a string, and then use the `any_of()` tidyselect helper.

Comment: I have tried it as well, it didn't work for some reason. Couldn't figure out why? I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Does this work for you: `Book1 %>% select(\`Row Labels\`, any_of("2023-05-01"))` What exactly is the content of `Time_Period`? It's hard to tell from an image

Comment: @MrFlick Time_Period = "2022-09-01" "2022-10-01" "2022-11-01" , that would work but when I pass it through the variable, it doesn't work. And since the aim is to get the code in such a manner that I don't have to mentioned the column names as the number of columns are very long in the actual dataset I am working on. I was trying to figure out a way around it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This should work: `Time_Period = c("2022-11-01","2023-01-01","2023-07-01"); Book1 %>% select(\`Row Labels\`, any_of(Time_Period))`. (here I used column names that actually exist in the sample data)

Comment: It should have right. That is why I was racking my brain around. I just realized the Time_Period <- add_months(max(ymd(Time)),1:3) returns data in date format and if I convert it to character Time_Period <-as.character(add_months(max(ymd(Time)),1:freq)), it ideally should work. Let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249454/discussion-between-user20203146-and-mrflick).